# Assignment char to char - unexpected behaviour

Tags: c, pointers, char, variable-assignment

I expected that after

```
*b = a[0]
```

line:

```
printf("%c\n", *b);
```

would print first character from string a. Here is my short code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    char a[20];
    char* b;

    scanf("%s", a);
    printf("a: %s\n", a);
    *b=a[0]; // I suppose something here is wrong
    printf("%c\n",*b);


    return 0;}
```

For input:

```
STRING
```

Output is:

```
a: STRING
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

As far as I know, segmentation fault occurs when we try to access to memory which isn't allocated (staticaly or dinamicaly).
Here, b is pointer to char and it takes 8 bytes since my OS is 64-bit.
Using *b we dereference pointer, i.e access to it's content.
b has type char*, a[0] has type char and *b has type char. What's wrong?

Comment: Sure, the pointer *itself* is 64 bits, but where does it point to? And who allocated that content?

Comment: @Angew You are saying that even if I allocated space for pointer(by char* b), I have to allocate space for variables to which b will point? Like we call malloc to allocate space for array which has dimension n, I should in some way allocate space for this single char?

Comment: That's right. Well, you could make it point to something that already exists, but your line of `*b=a[0];` says "take the first element of `a` and copy to the place where `b` points". For that, it must already be pointing somewhere valid.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that you didn't allocate any `char` for `b` to point to, yet you try to write to where `b` points, that's why it crashes.

You probably wanted something like:

```
b = &a[0]
```

Now `b` contains the address of the first element of `a`, that's `&a[0]` (which also happens to be the same address that you get with `a`, by the way).

Alternatively, if you want `b` to point to its own `char` and copy the first char like in your code, you could allocate memory for it beforehand:

```
b = malloc(sizeof(char));   // after this, *b=a[0]; can be done
```

And if you do that, don't forget to free that memory when you're done:

```
free(b);
```

Comment: "_which also happens to just be `a`, by the way_" is incorrect or imprecise: the compiler _decays_ the name of the array `a`  to a pointer, "which also happens to be the address of `a[0]`, by the way"

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> `*b=a[0];`

you have a crash because you dereference *b* while it wasn't initialized

so you write in an unknown address and by chance that address is invalid and produce the crash, the worst is when the write is possible